# Testing Vue Components - Mocking State and Methods

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-test-utils

I've been trying to get my head around unit testing Vue components, but I can't seem to quite work out how to Mock/Stub out store objects and methods that call an API async.

This is an example of a Vue component we have:

```
import { mapState, mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import router from 'components/admin/router'

export default {
name: 'Users',
computed: {
    ...mapState('admin', [
        'users',
    ]),
    ...mapGetters({
        requestInProgress: 'requestInProgress',
    }),
},
data: function() {
    return {
        filterTerm: '',
        usersLoaded: false,
    }
},
methods: {        
    getUsers(filter) {
            this.$store.dispatch('admin/getUserList', filter)
                .then(res => {
                    this.usersLoaded = true
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    this.$toast.error({
                        title: 'Failed to retrieve data',
                        message: this.$options.filters.normaliseError(e),
                    })
                })            
    },
},
mounted() {
    this.getUsers('*')
},
```

}

And this is the test I want to write. I can't even get the test to run cleanly without actually trying to assert anything

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Users from 'components/admin/pages/user/users.vue'

describe('Users Vue', () => {
    it('Page Should Load', () => {
     const mockResponse = {
          data: [{
            "id": "1",
            "emailAddress": "beakersoft@gmail.com",
            "firstName": "Luke",
            "lastName": "Niland",
            "staffNumber": "12345",
            "phoneNumber": "07707 999999",
            "active": true
        }
    ]};

    let actions
    let store

    beforeEach(() => {
        actions = {
            'admin/getUserList': sinon.stub()                      
                  .returns(Promise.resolve(mockResponse))
        }
        store = new Vuex.Store({
            state: {},
            actions
        })
    })                   

    const wrapper = shallowMount(Users, { store })

    const h5 = wrapper.find('h5')
    expect(h5.text()).toBe('User Administration')  
  })
 })
```

The errors I tend to get back are about items being undefined, normally, in this case, `$store.dispatch` is `undefined`. I feel like I'm missing something with the mocking somewhere, or the fact that the `getUsers()` being called on the mount is tripping it up.

Comment: who calls filterUsers? maybe the this context of filterUsers is wrong?

Comment: Copy paste code fail, its getting called on the mount of the component. Updated the code

Comment: Did you use a [localVue](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#localvue) instance in your tests? Without it your mock store will not be attached to anything, I suppose. See [here](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#testing-vuex-in-components).

Answer (score 2):

In order to test a Vue component mocking Vuex as you're doing in your example, it is ok to pass a mock `store` to Vue when you `shallowMount` your component as you're doing, so:

```
shallowMount(Users, { store })
```

but this mock `store` needs to be mounted also to the base Vue constructor. To do so, you have to pass it to a - `localVue`. A `localVue` is a scoped Vue constructor that you can make changes to, in the testing scope, without affecting the global Vue constructor actually used in your application.

Moreover, in your specific case, you did not neither imported nor installed Vuex.

Then, to properly configure your test you need to:

1. create a `localVue` instance by invoking the Vue Test Utils utility `createLocalVue` function and install Vuex on it:

```
    import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
    import Vuex from 'vuex'

    //creating the local Vue instance for testing
    const localVue = createLocalVue()

    //mounting Vuex to it
    localVue.use(Vuex)
```

2. Changing your `shallowMount` function adding also the `localVue` instance to the payload:

```
 const wrapper = shallowMount(Users, { store, localVue })
```

See [here](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#testing-vuex-in-components) for the Official Documentation references.

Another useful resource about Vue testing is [this book](https://www.manning.com/books/testing-vue-js-applications) (for your specific case, see Chapter 7) and [its GitHub repository](https://github.com/eddyerburgh/vue-hackernews)

Answer (score 1):

You must create a local Vue to your tests and install Vuex plugin:

```js
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

localVue.use(Vuex)

const wrapper = shallowMount(...)
```